# Why video size is increasing after adding watermark to video using FFMPEG?

Tags: android, android-studio, video, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am adding watermark to video using FFMPEG where i use `-preset ultrafast` in FFMPEG command.which add watermark to video very fast but due to this my output video size increased.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i mt.png -filter_complex "overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2" -codec:a copy -preset ultrafast output.mp4
```

Without Using `-preset ultrafast`

input video size 5MB and output video size 5MB

Using `-preset ultrafast`

input video size 5MB and output video size 11MB

Comment: Fast encoding (transcoding in your case) foregoes many of the optimization steps in favor of speedy encoding, with the result that the output size suffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [FFMPEG documentation](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) says:

> A preset is a collection of options that will provide a certain encoding speed to compression ratio. A slower preset will provide better compression (compression is quality per filesize). This means that, for example, if you target a certain file size or constant bit rate, you will achieve better quality with a slower preset. Similarly, for constant quality encoding, you will simply save bitrate by choosing a slower preset.

In other words there is a trade off between encoding speed and space optimization/compression
. 
Try going for other preset like veryfast or superfast